# Size of flexible array member with brace initialisation

Tags: c

Let's say I have this code:

```
const struct
{
  const char * const name;
  const unsigned length;
  const char data[951357];
} var[] =
{
  {
    "dataset1",
    #include "dataset1.h"
  },
  {
    "dataset2",
    #include "dataset2.h"
  },
  /* ... */
};
```

Each `dataset*.h` contains something like:

```
6,
{
  0x04, 0x08, 0x15, 0x16, 0x23, 0x42
}
```

This requires me to know in advance the size of the largest dataset. The is not future-proof as anyone who adds a dataset also has to check and maybe modify the size of `data`, and can lead to serious memory waste *(in my real case, there are already ~15 datasets, with sizes ranging in the hundreds of KB)*.

Is there any way around that?

The only hard requirement is that each data must be in its own file, but that file's format can be anything. I would also like to keep everything as `const` as possible.

Edit: I should mention that the old code was doing this:

```
struct dataset { char* name; int length; char* data; };
struct dataset *alldata[10];
struct dataset dataset1 = {
  "dataset1",
  #include "dataset1.h"
};
/* same again for every dataset */
int main()
{
  alldata[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct dataset));
  memcpy(alldata[0], dataset1, sizeof(struct dataset));
  /* again, block copied for each dataset */
}
```

That code looks ugly to me, and requires (I think) unnecessary mem copies. My goal when rewriting that code was to make it store all the data at compile time, and then only read it when necessary at run time.

Comment: Does array need to be inside the struct? Would pointer suffice?

Comment: Are all those `const` around your `struct` definition mandatory?

Comment: `const char const * name;` seems like an error. Maybe you meant `char const * const name;`? Also, only one is needed for array: `char const data[951357];`.

Comment: Yes, I may have put too many `const` :]  
The goal is to put the whole struct into the .data (or .rodata) section of the binary.

Comment: I meant `.text` or `.rodata`, but that's not really important. I edited the question to fix those `const` and clarify where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pointer to data. You pay the price for extra pointer, but considering the size of your data, you save a lot by not having too big arrays.

```
#include "dataset1.h"
/* other dataset includes here */
struct DataSet {
    const char * name;
    unsigned length;
    const char * data;
};
const struct DataSet var[] = {
     {
         "dataset1",
        dataset1_length,
        dataset1_data,
     },
     /* other dataset inits here */
};
```

**dataset1.h**

```
enum { dataset1_length = 6 };
extern const char dataset1_data[];
```

**dataset1.c**

```
const char dataset1_data[] = { 0x04, 0x08, 0x15, 0x16, 0x23, 0x42 };
```

Note how I removed unnecessary `const`s, yet all data is still `const`.

If having extra compilation units is not wanted, just combine header and source file into one header and include that directly:

**dataset1.h**

```
enum { dataset1_length = 6 };
const char dataset1_data[] = { 0x04, 0x08, 0x15, 0x16, 0x23, 0x42 };
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but the compiler was complaining about `dataset1_data` not being compile-time const (or something like that, I don't remember exactly). I'll try again, maybe I was just putting my `const` in the wrong places :)

Comment: @1ace Maybe it had something to do with `char* data;` not being a `const` in your old code?

Comment: I'm an idiot: the problem was with `length` not being compile-time constant, not the `data` :]

Comment: while I do not agree with the suggestion to place an instance of the data into a header file, Overall this is a very good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You want create an array of structures. An array requires that the size of each element is the same. Said that you cannot create any array using structures of different sizes, due to the flexible array, unless you fix the size of the array member (as you're doing).
There is a solution anyway. Change the variable length array member with a pointer and create the variable size array elsewhere.
The solution that I'll explain let's you continue to use the array accessing method, so you don't have to change the rest of software, and requires just a small modification to your header files.
The main structure declaration will then be:

```
const struct
{
  const char const * name;
  const unsigned length;
  const char const *data;    //This is the only difference
} var[] =
{
  {
    "dataset1",
    #include "dataset1.h"
  },
  {
    "dataset2",
    #include "dataset2.h"
  },
  /* ... */
};
```

The header files will be crafted as follow:

```
6,
(const char const *)&(const char[]) {0x04, 0x08, 0x15, 0x16, 0x23, 0x42}
```

Here the part `(const char[]){0x04, 0x08, 0x15, 0x16, 0x23, 0x42}` creates in memory an array of `char` constants of variable length. Then with operator `&` we get its address and cast it to a char pointer before assigning it to the structure.
Tested under C99-C11